# Нужно написать будильник с Date, Calendar

Tags: java

Нужно написать простой будильник, который будет выводить сообщение в консоль, при подобном условии:

real_time >= my_time или real_time = my_time;

где real_time - объект Date, реальное время. 
    my_time -, например 12:00.

Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно в цикле сделать задержку, например 100мс и проверять каждый раз условие и выводить сообщение.

Можно попробовать использовать что-то из стандартной библиотеки [это](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) или [это](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), но тут скорее всего придется рассчитывать задержку до срабатывания, что в принципе не сложно.

Так же очень много различных примеров или подсказок есть в интернете.
Вы можете воспользоваться поисковиком это бесплатно и без смс.

Comment: Bleser, я искал в интернете, там, без смс и регестрации, всё заточено под андроид, а мне нужен софт под пк.

Comment: На мой взгляд самое лучшее решение не писать костыли с циклами, а использовать нормальные инструменты которые я привел в ссылках. Первая ссылка это класс из более старой версии java, а вторая из более новой. Нужно просто из нужного времени вычесть текущее(предварительно можно перевести в мс или использовать java 8 time api) и установить результат как задержку до срабатывания.

Answer (score 0):

Еще, как вариант, можно использовать класс Calendar. У него есть методы before() и after(). С их помощью можно сравнивать объекты классов. Или возвращать время(метод getTimeInMillis()) в мс и сравнивать int обычными математическими операциями. А дальше все как Bleser написал: "Можно в цикле сделать задержку, например 100мс и проверять каждый раз условие и выводить сообщение." Только, я бы сделал задержку в 1000мс. Для будильника не нужна такая точность.

Еще есть классы LocalTime, LocalDate, LocalDateTime в java8. Да и вообще посмотреть новое Date Time API из java8. Там много про дату и время.